# Different methods access in different classes

Tags: java

Below is the code structure:
I want class C to only access M1() of class A & M3() of class B, other methods like M2() & M4() should not be visible here.
And class D to access M2() of class A & M4() of class B, other methods like M1() & M3() should not be visible here.

Code packages, access levels modifications is permitted. Just wanna achieve above thing.

```
public class A{
    <access_specifier> void M1()
    {

    }
    <access_specifier> void M2()
    {

    }
}

public class B{
    <access_specifier> void M3()
    {

    }
    <access_specifier> void M4()
    {

    }
}

public class C{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    }
}

public class D{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this requirement? Maybe another approach would be better

Comment: Seems like homework about visibility to me. Is it the case?

Comment: Also,in Java - it is a strong convention that methods start with lower case letters, so it should be `m1(), m2(), ...` and NOT `M1(), M2() ,....`.

Comment: You mean your teacher? Can you tell us, what you've tried already?

Comment: which access specifiers do you know?

Comment: well, since you know all, you should think about what the differences are and which are obviously useful or useless

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is not possible using standard Java access modifiers.

If `C` can see `A.m1` but not `A.m2`, then we know that `A.m2` cannot be public, and `A.m1` cannot be private.  And because `D` sees `A.m2` but not `A.m1`, we know that they can neither be public nor private.

So they will have to be protected or package-private (default) access.  And since we know that we want different access to these methods, each will have to have a different modifier.  Thus one is `protected`, and the other is package-private.

However, we want `C` and `D` to both be able to access one of these but not the other.  No matter how we arrange these other classes, `protected` is always a strict superset of package-private, since it allows access to everything in the package *and* subclasses.  There's no way we could arrange `C` or `D`, so that it can access a package-private method but *not* see a `protected` method.

---

In fact, in a more general sense, the access modifiers form a hierarchy.  If you can "see" one of the modifiers, then you can see all of the modifiers above it as well.  Therefore it's clearly impossible to have the mutual exclusive condition where `C` sees `m1` but not `m2`, and `D` sees `m2` but not `m1`.